# SoftLayer API: How to get the blockDevice information from a image template?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

[image]

I have a image template as shown in the picture. I want to get the disk space and the virtual disks list as marked in the Figure. I used:

`http://sldn.softlayer.com/zh/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getObject to get the image template with mask as ('mask[id,accountId,name,globalIdentifier,blockDevices[device,diskImageId,diskSpace,groupId,id,units],parentId,createDate,datacenter,imageType,storageRepository,datacenters]')`.

The mask blockDevices is set. But the result is as flows:

```
{'accountId': xxxxxxx,
 'blockDevices': [],
 'createDate': '2016-09-18T07:16:57-05:00',
 'datacenters': [{'id': xx4092,
                  'longName': 'Singapore 1',
                  'name': 'sng01',
                  'statusId': 2}],
 'globalIdentifier': 'xxxxxxxx-b068-40b1-8377-9ab66df80131',
 'id': 1331697,
 'imageType': {'description': 'a disk that may be replaced on upgrade',
               'keyName': 'SYSTEM',
               'name': 'System'},
 'name': 'xxx-test-all-disk',
 'parentId': ''}
```

The item of blockDevices is a empty array. Why?

Any api can help me to get the image disk space and virtual disks info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following `mask` (This a Rest example):

```
 https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/[imageId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,name,children[id,name,blockDevices[diskSpace,units,diskImage[localDiskFlag]]]]

Method:GET
```

The `children` items contain the information that you want. Currently, you are trying to get of `parent`item.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your perfect answer.  Use your mask, I have get the result( children:[{blockDevice:[{device:0,...}]}]), but how can I get the device type(san or local?) .  Does any other mask can help?

Comment: you could add `localDiskFlag`to your mask (children>blockDevices>diskImage>localDiskFlag). Please try it and see if it works for you :). I updated the above request using this property.

Comment: Well, what a complicated API it is. The api doc is not detail for each item of     the mask. There are so many refers from one item to another which puzzled me so much.  Anyway, you are so kind, thanks again for your help.